# Shorten or merge multiple lines of `&> /dev/null &`

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect, background-process

Every time starting the machine, I run the following program:

```
$ cat start.sh
#! /bin/bash
google-chrome &> /dev/null &
lantern &> /dev/null &
xdg-open . &> /dev/null &
emacs &> /dev/null  &
code ~/Programs/ &> /dev/null &
xdg-open ~/Reference/topic_regex.md &> /dev/null &
```

Cumbersome `&> /dev/null &`...
How could I shorten the logic?

Comment: You can put all or most of those programs in your [Startup Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/startup-applications.html.en).

Comment: great, fantastic application. Errors usually occurred to  gnome-session causing abrupt crashing, so I start them from tmux server. @DennisWilliamson

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The part `&> /dev/null` means output redirection. You can redirect multiple commands to the same file by grouping them into a block:

```
#! /bin/bash
{
google-chrome &
lantern &
xdg-open . &
emacs  &
code ~/Programs/ &
xdg-open ~/Reference/topic_regex.md &
} &> /dev/null
```

The same thing, however, cannot be used to start individual commands in the background (`&`). Putting `&` after the block would mean running the whole block as a single script in the background.

Comment: Do note that the `&>` syntax is deprecated and should be replaced with `>/dev/null 2>&1` http://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: @multithr3at3d A Bashism incompatible with POSIX? Sure! Deprecated or obsolete? **No**, regardless of what the three authors of this list last edited in 2015 think. It is a short form, and shortening command lines is exactly OP’s goal here. If someone runs a `#!/bin/bash` script in a different shell without checking for portability first it’s definitely not Bash’s fault if it doesn’t work.

Comment: I assume that i can not have it on s!ngle line..

Answer (score 14):

I wrote a function and put it into my `.bashrc` to run 
things detached from my terminal:

```
detach () 
{ 
    ( "$@" &> /dev/null & )
}
```

... and then:

```
detach google-chrome
detach xdg-open ~/Reference/topic_regex.md
```

And because I'm lazy, I also wrote a shortcut for `xdg-open`:

```
xo () 
{ 
    for var in "$@"; do
        detach xdg-open "$var";
    done
}
```

Because `xdg-open` expects exactly one argument, the function `xo` iterates
over all given arguments and calls `xdg-open` for each one separately.

This allows for:

```
detach google-chrome
xo . ~/Reference/topic_regex.md
```

Answer (score 5):

You could redirect the output for all subsequent commands with

```
exec 1>/dev/null
exec 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a special file like `/dev/null` with a shorter path to shorten the redirection. I used `/n` as the new file’s path:

```
sudo mknod -m 0666 /n c 1 3
```

This way you can shorten the individual lines to e.g.:

```
google-chrome &>/n &
```

Source: [How to create /dev/null?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27279/246819)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a loop and give it the commands as arguments:

```bsh
for i in google-chrome "xdg-open ." "code ~/Programs/"; do
  $i &
done &>/dev/null
```

Note that this way exactly as with the subshell approach with curly braces it’s possible to sum up the outputs and redirect all of them at once.