# xdg-open: Open various tab at the same time

Tags: 18.04, firefox, chromium, browser, xdg-open

I am trying to open various tab at the same time using `xdg-open` my default browser is firefox.

The following line works (for one tab):

```
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com
```

But this one does not:

```
xdg-open https://stackoverflow.com https://google.fr
```

the error thrown is:

> xdg-open: unexpected argument 'https://google.fr'

Isn't it any way of passing various URL to `xdg-open`? Thanks in advance !

Comment: You'll need to provide the actual browser name and urls separated by spaces. `xdg-open` doesn't do what you want. It takes a single argument. See `man xdg-open`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with `xdg-open` alone because it expects *exactly* one argument.
But you can write a function to iterate over all given arguments and call
`xdg-open` separately.

Open your `~/.bashrc` file in an editor, e.g.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and then add the following text at the end of the file:

```
xo () 
{ 
    for var in "$@"; do
        xdg-open "$var";
    done
}
```

Save the file and leave the editor. After that either close and re-open the terminal
window or enter

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in the current window for the change to take effect. 
From now on you have a new *command* `xo` and can issue

```
xo https://stackoverflow.com https://google.fr
```

See also [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145023/504066) to the slightly related question
[Shorten or merge multiple lines of `&> /dev/null &`](https://askubuntu.com/q/1145017/504066).

Comment: Thanks, I decided to rename it `xdg-open-multi`

Comment: About `source ~/.bashrc` should I run it everytime before I wanna use `xdg-open-multi` ?

Comment: @Ced No. If you have put it in your `~/.bashrc` file, it is read (and the function is defined) every time you open a _new_ terminal. The `source ...` command is only neccessary when you changed (added) the definition and want to use it immediately in the _current_ window without closing and re-opening it.

Comment: Good to know thanks a lot! :D I'll let this question open if any others people have anything to suggest, and then I'll accept your answer in few days

Comment: @Ced Glad to hear. You are welcome. Simply spoken: whenever you open a new terminal window, the command `source ~/.bashrc` is automatically run and all definitions and/or commands in that file are executed. The manual call of `source...` is only needed if you want to re-run the definitions and/or commands from `~/.bashrc` without opening a new window.

Answer (score 1):

A simple open function to open file/url (multiple) 
and the new application disown to the terminal

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function openn() {
  if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "You must enter 1 or more command line arguments";
  elif [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    xdg-open "$1" > /dev/null & disown;
  else
    for file in "$@"; do
      xdg-open "$file" > /dev/null & disown;
    done
  fi
}
```